# How to get finalized revenue through the YouTube API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

The YouTube Analytics API provides access to *estimated* revenue [through the Metrics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets#estimatedRevenue). However, these are just estimates, and are not the final amount that creators are actually paid. Anecdotally, actual revenue can often be significantly different from these estimates. [YouTube documentation](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1714384) notes that:

> Finalized revenue can be found in the downloadable monthly reports approximately 10 days after month end and are visible on the AdSense payment page within 15 days after a month’s end.

Is there any way to access this data through an API? I don't mind waiting 15 or even 30 days to get access to this, but I need to get the actual final amount that the creator was paid in a month, and I need to get that information per-video. I haven't found anything in the Analytics API so far, but I'm not intimately familiar with the YouTube API so I may be missing something.

Comment: I haven't try this but do check the [AdSense API](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/) to see if the reporting you want to have is there. Hope this helps.